# Why the string slicing lead to this kind of result? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I managed to do circular shift of characters by string slicing and use the strcat() method to combine the 2 slices.

Here is my example code:

```
>> a = '917'
>> b = strcat(a(2:1:3) ,a(1:1:1))
   b =
       '179'
```

However, I once tried the following code and accidentally obtained the sequent result… A 1X2 double Array.

```
>> b = a(2:1:3) + a(1:1:1)
   b =
       106   112
```

Can anyone help me to explain the output? Why b = [106 112]?
THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have are [character arrays](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) rather than [strings](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html); strings are a fairly new class in MATLAB defined using double quotes. But character arrays are basically a numeric array of ASCII (or to be more precise, UTF-16) code points under the hood.

`strcat` by definition concatenates character arrays (or strings). This is equivalent to regular array concatenation syntax:

```
>> strcat('17', '9')

ans =

    '179'

>> ['17', '9']      

ans =

    '179'
```

However, any arithmetic operation will coerce character arrays to become the underlying integer array:

```
>> +'179'      

ans =

    49    55    57
```

Those numbers are the ASCII code points for `1`, `7` and `9`, respectively. ASCII is a subset of UTF-16, so for numbers, English letters and punctuation it suffices to think in terms of ASCII code points.

Now you'll see why adding two character arrays will perform the corresponding operation that adds the numeric arrays:

```
>> '17' + '9'

ans =

   106   112

>> [49 55] + [57]

ans =

   106   112
```

The above also means that you were unlucky. If the two character arrays had incompatible size (i.e. if their size were unequal and neither were of length 1) you'd have gotten an error instead:

```
>> '12' + '345'
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Since you can't add a 2-length and a 3-length vector.

Comment: @CrisLuengo why would anyone ever use anything other than ascii?! ;) Thanks, clarified.